# A big arrow crossing several states in automata with TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have six states in an automata drawing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm,thick,every state/.style={minimum size=3cm}]
  \node[state,draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (A) {A};
  \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (B) [right of=A] {B};
  \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (E) [below of=B] {E};
  \node[state,draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (C) [right of=B] {C};
  \node[state,draw=green!50!black,fill=green!20] (D) [below of=A] {D};
  \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (F) [below of=C] {F};
  \path[-,violet,line width=1mm]
  (A) edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G1,G2,G3} (E)
  edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G1} (B)
  (D) edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G4} (E)
  (C) edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G5} (E)
  edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G5} (F)
  (E) edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G5} (F)
  (B) edge node [color=black,sloped,above] {G1} (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this

[image]

What I want now is to draw a big arrow, touching all the nodes with a text on it.

[This example is amazing](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circular-arrows-text/) but I have no Idea how to modify it in order to pass through the nodes.

I want something like this:

[image]

But looking nicer (and with TiKZ, the previous image was done in inkscape)

Comment: 'Looking nicer' is rather vague. Your nicer might be my horribler, for example. Overlaying the text and lines shouldn't be a problem but since you don't want it to look like the image you've posted, what should it look like exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This demonstrates one way to superimpose a path with text curved along it. A wide path is drawn using a thick, translucent line. A `text along path` decoration is used to add the text after the line is drawn in a `postaction`. Finally, the path is given opaque edges by drawing two additional paths over the first using thin, edging lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,positioning,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      node distance=5cm,
      thick,
      every state/.style={minimum size=3cm},
      every edge/.append style={
        every node/.append style={text=black, sloped, above}
      },
    ]
    \node[state,draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (A) {A};
    \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (B) [right=of A.center] {B};
    \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (E) [below=of B.center] {E};
    \node[state,draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (C) [right=of B.center] {C};
    \node[state,draw=green!50!black,fill=green!20] (D) [below=of A.center] {D};
    \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (F) [below=of C.center] {F};
    \path[-,violet,line width=1mm]
    (A)  edge node  {G1,G2,G3}
    (E)  edge node [below]  {G1} (B)
    (D)  edge node  {G4} (E)
    (C)  edge node  {G5} (E)
         edge node  {G5} (F)
    (E)  edge node  {G5} (F)
    (B)  edge node  {G1} (E);
    \path
    [
      line width=7.5mm,
      draw=violet!25,
      opacity=.75,
    ] ($(B.north)!1/2!(E.south)$) coordinate (c) circle (75mm and 40mm);
    \path
    [
      thick,
      draw=violet,
    ] (c) circle (78.75mm and 43.75mm) circle (71.25mm and 36.25mm)
    ;
    \path
    [
      postaction={
        decorate,
        opacity=1,
        decoration={
          text along path,
          text={|\LARGE\sffamily|Some text here Some text here ||},
          raise=-5pt,
          pre length=200mm,
          text color=black,
          reverse path=true,
          pre=moveto
        }
      }
    ]  (c) circle (75mm and 40mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: curved text]

## EDIT

Here's an example somewhat similar to the one you linked in your question. It uses thick arrows with text decorations.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,positioning,decorations.text,arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      node distance=5cm,
      thick,
      every state/.style={minimum size=3cm},
      every edge/.append style={
        every node/.append style={text=black, sloped, above}
      },
      my arrow/.style={line width=7.5mm, draw=violet, {Triangle Cap[reversed,bend]}-{Triangle Cap[bend]}},
    ]
    \node[state,draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (A) {A};
    \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (B) [right=of A.center] {B};
    \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (E) [below=of B.center] {E};
    \node[state,draw=blue,fill=blue!20] (C) [right=of B.center] {C};
    \node[state,draw=green!50!black,fill=green!20] (D) [below=of A.center] {D};
    \node[state,draw=red,fill=red!20] (F) [below=of C.center] {F};
    \path[-,violet,line width=1mm]
    (A)  edge node  {G1,G2,G3}
    (E)  edge node [below]  {G1} (B)
    (D)  edge node  {G4} (E)
    (C)  edge node  {G5} (E)
         edge node  {G5} (F)
    (E)  edge node  {G5} (F)
    (B)  edge node  {G1} (E);
    \path [my arrow]  ($(B.north)!1/2!(E.south)$) coordinate (c) +(75mm,0) arc (0:-90:75mm and 40mm);
    \path [my arrow] (c) +(0,-40mm) arc (270:180:75mm and 40mm);
    \path
    [
      my arrow,
      postaction=decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        text={|\LARGE\sffamily|Some text here Some text here ||},
        text color=white,
        raise=-5pt,
        pre length=10mm,
        pre=moveto
        }
    ] (c) +(-75mm,0) arc (180:90:75mm and 40mm);
    \path
    [
      my arrow,
      postaction=decorate,
      decoration={
        text along path,
        text={|\LARGE\sffamily|More text here More text here ||},
        text color=white,
        raise=-5pt,
        pre length=10mm,
        pre=moveto
        }
    ]  (c) +(0,40mm) arc (90:0:75mm and 40mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows on automata]

Comment: Sorry for my vague definition... but your second version is definitely nicer than my sketch ;-)

Comment: @AlejandroDC Glad it helped. It is just that when people say 'nicer', there's the problem that people's tastes differ - sometimes radically ;). Note that the `[bend]` slows compilation a bit but without it, it looked awful. So I think it is worth it. (And unless you are drawing lots and lots of these, it shouldn't really be noticeable, I wouldn't think.) TikZ uses a short-cut for arrows by default because these are more 'expensive'.