# Time table with big arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows

Is it possible to create a table like the one shown in the figure below with LaTeX?

I don't care much about the colors as I care about the arrows and the fact that the arrows are crossing cells. The table looks empty, but I would eventually also put some text inside the arrows and in the task column. I know how to create a table, but from that point forward I'm lost. It seems that this could be accomplished using the `tikz` package as I found [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240933/a-big-arrow-crossing-several-states-in-automata-with-tikz).

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}

% increase table row spacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

% command for colored cells
\newcommand{\scell}[1]{\cellcolor{black!25} \it #1 }

% hatched table
\newcommand\HatchedCell[4][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \fill[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (0,1.9ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (0pt,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\newcommand*{\hatch}[2]{\multicolumn{#2}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\tikzmark{start#1}}c!{\tikzmark{end#1}}}{}}

% roman numbers
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
    Activity & \multicolumn{10}{c}{semester} \\
     & \scriptsize{1} & \scriptsize{2} & \scriptsize{3} & \scriptsize{4} & \scriptsize{5} & \scriptsize{6} & \scriptsize{7} & \scriptsize{8} & \scriptsize{9} & \scriptsize{10} \\
    \toprule
   \multicolumn{11}{l}{\scell{Theme 1}}  \\
   Task 1  & & \hatch{1}{1}  & \\
   Task 2  & & \hatch{2}{2} & & & & & & & \\
   Task 3  & & \hatch{4}{6} \\
   \multicolumn{11}{l}{\scell{Theme 2}}  \\
   Task 1  & & \hatch{2}{2} & & & & & & & \\
   \multicolumn{11}{l}{\scell{Theme 3}}  \\
   Task 1  & & \hatch{2}{2} & & & & & & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \rowcolor{white}
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table with rows.}
\label{tab:work_plan}

% loop over odd rows
\foreach \x/\y  in {1/1,3/3,5/5}{
  \HatchedCell{start\x}{end\y}{%
     pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}
}
\foreach \x/\y  in {2/2,4/4,6/6}{
  \HatchedCell{start\x}{end\y}{%
    pattern color=black!70,pattern=north west lines}
}
\end{table}[![enter image description here][3]][3]

\end{document}
```

which creates this table:

[image]

**UPDATE**

So after taking a look at [this post](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/kalman-filter/), I tried my best to come up with something and this is what I got so far: 
[image]

For which the code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes.symbols,calc,shadings,patterns,tikzmark,decorations.pathmorphing,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

% styles
\tikzstyle{none}=[]
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[signal, minimum height=0.7cm, fill=LightGray, signal to]
\tikzstyle{background}=[rectangle,
                                                fill=gray!10,
                                                inner sep=0.2cm,
                                                rounded corners=5mm]

\tikzstyle{darkBackground}=[rectangle,
                                                fill=gray!50,
                                                inner sep=0.2cm]



\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.25ex, minimum width=1.5cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ]
    % "text height" and "text depth" are required to vertically
    % align the labels with and without indices.

  % The various elements are conveniently placed using a matrix:
  \matrix[row sep=0.5cm,column sep=0.5cm] {
    % First line: Control input
        \node (1) {1}; & \node (2) {2}; & \node (3) {3}; & \node (4) {4}; & \node (5) {5}; & \node (Task) {Task}; \\
        % Second line
         \node (Theme-1) [] {}; & & & &  \node (End-Theme-1) [] {}; \\
        % Third line
        \node (A-1-1) [] {}; & & & &  & \node (Task1) [] {First task of theme 1}; \\
        % Fourth line
        \node (A-2-1) [] {}; & & & &  & \node (Task2) [] {Second task of theme 1}; \\
        % Fifth line
         \node (Theme-2) [] {}; & & & &  \node (End-Theme-2) [] {}; \\
        % Sixth line
         & \node (A-3-2) [] {}; & & &  & \node (Task3) [] {First task of theme 2}; \\
        % Seventh line
         & \node (A-4-2) [] {}; & & &  & \node (Task4) [] {Second task of theme 2}; \\
        % Eighth line
         \node (Theme-3) [] {}; & & & &  \node (End-Theme-3) [] {}; \\
        % Ninth line
        &  \node (A-5-2) [] {}; & & &  \node (A-5-5) [] {}; & \node (Task5) [] {First task of theme 3}; \\


        % Fifth line: Measurement
         \node (Milestones) [] {}; &
        \node (z_k-1) [] {1}; &
        &
        \node (z_k)   [] {2};     &
        \\
    };

    % draw arrows
    \node[myarrow, minimum width=3cm, anchor=west] at (A-1-1.west) {};
    \node[myarrow, minimum width=1.5cm, anchor=west] at (A-2-1.west) {};
    \node[myarrow, minimum width=3cm, anchor=west] at (A-3-2.west) {};
    \node[myarrow, minimum width=1.5cm, anchor=west] at (A-4-2.west) {};
    \node[myarrow, minimum width=4cm, anchor=west] at (A-5-2.west) {};


    % Now that the diagram has been drawn, background rectangles
    % can be fitted to its elements. This requires the TikZ
    % libraries "fit" and "background".
    % Control input and measurement are labeled. These labels have
    % not been translated to English as "Measurement" instead of
    % "Messung" would not look good due to it being too long a word.
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node [none,
                    fit=(1) (5),
                    label=left:Year:] {};
        \node [none,
                    fit=(Milestones),
                    label=left:Milestones:] {};
        \node [background,
                    fit=(1) (A-5-5)] {};
        \node [darkBackground,
                    fit=(Theme-1) (End-Theme-1), label=center:Theme 1] {};
        \node [darkBackground,
                    fit=(Theme-2) (End-Theme-2), label=center:Theme 2] {};
        \node [darkBackground,
                    fit=(Theme-3) (End-Theme-3), label=center:Theme 3] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now there are many things I would like to improve and I need your help finishing it. First, the Task column should be left-justified. Is there a way to set the arrow length for the year duration in a better way? Any suggestions that could improve the appearance of the table is very welcome.

Comment: So please post the code you've got for the table and somebody can then help you with the arrows.

Comment: @cfr I modified my question.

Comment: @arragom, and which image you like to obtain. The first one (in color) or what you generated with your code? Do you like in it replace hatched nodes with arrows?

Comment: I would like to replace the hatched code by arrows, in the same way I posted the color picture.

Comment: @aaragon, you  complete change your answer and with this made received answers obsolete! My opinion: it would be better to ask new question, but before that rethinking about design of your time table (from your comments I concluded different design intention) and than clearly ask, what is your problem.

Comment: @Zarko it's still the same question. If you see my original question, I'm trying to approach to the original figure as much as I can. I still have to figure out a way to make the arrows cross boundaries (an arrow should overlap two rows), and also, I don't like the formatting I currently have so much. But the answer is almost there.

Comment: @aaragon, if you say so :-). As you can see, all answers on your first vesion of question, doesn't consider your new goal: optimizing code, which you prepare now, they aren't aware for you new design approach. How you will award efforts of people, who have been already give you answers, that they wrote new ones? I wish you the best and happy TZeXing!

Comment: @Zarko, I don't know how to reward. What do you suggest?

Comment: @aaragon, with vote for answer (by click on pen on the left top side of answer) or by accepting of answer, which on the best way solve your problem. Sorry, SE send me warning, that we should avoid extended discussion ... so we need to finish with exchanges of comments :-(

Comment: The approach I used is the closest to your solution, so I have given you the answer to the post. Thanks @Zarko!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With standard `tabular` and use of `tikz` for `signal` shapes you can design following table:

[image]

Code is derived from your MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{event/.style = {baseline=-3pt,
E/.style args = {##1/##2}{shape=signal, draw, 
    minimum width=##1, minimum height=4mm,
    fill=##2,
    signal to=no where, signal to=east, 
    inner sep=1mm, node contents={}},
        }}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}l@{}|}{#2}}
\newcommand{\scell}[1]{\multicolumn{10}{c|}{\cellcolor{black!25}%
                                           \itshape Theme #1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}

    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{l|*{10}{P{11mm}|}}
    \cline{2-11}
    &   \multicolumn{10}{c|}{semester}                       \\
    \cline{2-11}
    &   \scriptsize{1} 
        &   \scriptsize{2} 
            &   \scriptsize{3} 
                &   \scriptsize{4} 
                    &   \scriptsize{5} 
    &   \scriptsize{6} 
        &   \scriptsize{7} 
            & \scriptsize{8}    
                &   \scriptsize{9} 
                    &   \scriptsize{10}                     \\
        &   \scell{1}\\ 
Task 1  &   \mc{1}{\tikz[event]\node[E=11mm/yellow!10];}
                &&&&&&&&&                                   \\
Task 2  &   &   \mc{2}{\tikz[event]\node[E=22mm/orange!10];}
                &&&&&&&                                     \\
        &   \scell{2}\\ 
Task 1  &&&   \mc{5}{\tikz[event]\node[E=55mm/green!10];}
                &&&                                         \\
Task 2  &&    \mc{5}{\tikz[event]\node[E=55mm/blue!10];}
                &&&&                                        \\
Task 3  &&&&  \mc{7}{\tikz[event]\node[E=77mm/purple!10];}  \\
    \cline{2-11}
\end{tabular}
%    \captionof{table}{Table with rows.}
%    \label{tab:work_plan}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In case, that more tasks has common shape `signal`, than it should be placed in `multirow`. For example:

```
Task 1  && && && && && \\
Task 2  &&   \mc{5}{\multirow{-2}*{
                    \tikz[event]\node[E=55mm/green!10,minimum height=7mm];}
                                 }
                &&&&                                            \\
```

Since "signal" now is used for two task, I make it taller.

The idea, that instead explicit determination of "signals" length be used `hsize` doesn't works correctly, so I erase it now.

Comment: Could I make the arrows overlap many tasks as in the figure I showed originally?

Comment: Common for 2 or more task? With the same heights? Yes, this is possible with use of `multirow` package. See  upgrade of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to use the `pgfgantt` package. This is based on TikZ, so you can customize the appearance of things accordingly. Here is an example that might help get you started.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[bar/.append style={shape=signal,fill=blue!20},x unit=7mm]{1}{10}
\gantttitle[title/.style={draw=none},title left shift=-1mm]{Activity}{-0}
\gantttitle{semester}{10}\\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,10}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Theme 1}{1}{10} \\
\ganttbar[inline]{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar{Task 2}{1}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Task 3}{1}{7} \\
\ganttgroup{Theme 2}{1}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Theme 3}{1}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{4}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach using the [`pgfgantt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) package (the [`other answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270272/3954) also suggests this package, but I had already written this example as an answer and has a different approach and shows new elements so I decided to add this answer). I defined a new element `arrbar` which has the desired arrow-like shape and also show how to produce the filled rectangles for the "themes":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\newganttchartelement{arrbar}{
arrbar/.style={
  shape={chamfered rectangle},
  chamfered rectangle corners={north east,south east},
  draw=cyan!70!black,
  very thick,
  top color=white,
  bottom color=cyan!50,
  },
arrbar incomplete/.style={
  /pgfgantt/foobar,
  draw=orange,
  bottom color=orange!50
},
  arrbar label font=\slshape,
  arrbar left shift=0,
  arrbar right shift=0,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  hgrid=true,
  vgrid={dotted,dotted},
  bar/.append style={fill=gray!30,text height=20pt}
]{1}{10}
\gantttitle{Semester}{10} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,10}{1} \\
\ganttbar[name=theme1]{}{1}{10}\\
\node at (theme1.center) {Theme 1};
\ganttarrbar{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
\ganttarrbar{Task 2}{2}{5} \\
\ganttbar[name=theme2]{}{1}{10}\\
\node at (theme2.center) {Theme 2};
\ganttarrbar[name=task3]{Task 3}{1}{7} \\
\node at (task3.center) {Test text};
\ganttarrbar{Task 4}{3}{5} \\
\ganttarrbar{Task 5}{4}{10}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity in this approach but would it be possible to make the arrows overlap many tasks as in the figure I showed originally?

Comment: @aaragon I'm afraid I don't understand. Could you please describe in more detail what do you mean with "make the arrows overlap many tasks"?